# How to create a relationship with cypher when two nodes of different types has the same value for a certain property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The two types of nodes are Address and Wallet respectively. The property to be matched is called primWallAddr.

I am not sure if this would work:

```
MATCH (addr:Address {primWallAddr}), (wa:Wallet {primWallAddr})
CREATE (addr)-[:belongsTo]->(wa)
```

Or do I have to use "where"? (If yes, an example would be nice)

Sorry for such a basic question. I want to be sure and could not find something comparable (in my opinion) online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your query a bit for it to work:

```
MATCH (addr:Address), (wa:Wallet) WHERE addr.primWallAddr=wa.primWallAddr
CREATE (addr)-[:belongsTo]->(wa)
```

Comment: So I would assume that "where" is essential? However, when I import a relation from csv, the match part of the command is, as an example "MATCH (inp:Input {AddId: row[0]}), (ta:Transaction {TranId: row[1]})" Is there any reason?

Comment: You can match like that by exact property value, otherwise you need WHERE statement. So exact match (n:Node{Id: 246}) works but ... match (p:Person) where p.name starts with 'an' needs a where statement